# Trigger a function on main timeline from a class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to trigger a function on the main timeline in my FLA from a class file. I can usually find the solution sifting through forum posts but all the ones i look at just aren't helping.

heres the code i have as of now, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
//this is the code in my as3 class file
var e:Event = new Event("runFunc",true)                  dispatchEvent(e)

//here is the code in my .fla       
addEventListener("runFunc", initialization);
```

I know using code in the FLA is a dirty method of coding but i am trying to add to a pre-existing game i had built previously.

Comment: this cant be all the code... you need to tie that event listener to the instance of your as3 class file..plus that isn't what a class file looks like

Comment: i posted more code as an "answer" to my own question. maybe it will give you a better understanding of what im trying to do :/

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to migrate your code off the timeline with this method..

```
// class file
public function Main() {
    //constructor
    this.addFrameScript(1, frameOneFunc);
    initialization();
}
private function frameOneFunc(){
    This is essentially code in timeline for frame one.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont quite follow you glad, Are you saying to cut my code out of the fla and paste it in the frameOneFunc in the class file?

Here is a little more code to go off of.

.fla code(the function im trying to run)

```
function initialization();
{
    //random code...
}
```

code in my class file

```
public function frame1()
{
    this.savedstuff = SharedObject.getLocal("myStuff");
    this.btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.SaveData);
    this.btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.LoadData);
    if (this.savedstuff.size > 0)
    {
//trying to trigger function here...this is my failed code below
            //MovieClip(parent).initialization();
            //var e:Event = new Event("runFunc",true)
             //dispatchEvent(e)
            //dispatchEvent(new Event("initialization"));
            this.nameField.y = 800

            this.note.y = 800

            this.btnSave.y = 800

            this.btnLoad.y = 800
            this.tigger.y = 0;

            trace(this.savedstuff.data.username);
        this.nameField.text = this.savedstuff.data.username;
        this.note.gotoAndStop(4);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why not just run all your functions from a class file? Setup your FLA with a document class (Properties panel). You should try and avoid using code on the timeline. Read through this tutorial real quick http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/

Comment: I have about 2000 lines of code on the main timeline already. trying to avoid moving that cod into a class if possible. :/